# There is way in C to insert a number of more than one digit from input in different positions of an array?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>  

int main(void)
{
    int a[5], i;

    printf("Enter a number\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        scanf("%d\n", &a[i]);
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you need to know, it's completely unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I should make an example:
Input:98765
a[0] = 9, a[1] = 8,...., a[4] = 5
There is a way to do this?
By the way,thank you so much!

Comment: Try `char buf[5]; scanf("%5c", buf);` then post-process the array.

Comment: `scanf("%d\n", &a[i]);` : remove `\n`. `scanf("%d", &a[i]);`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are needing, this is one of the occasions where it is better to read the initial number as character string and then process the string into the array of digits. While there are a number of ways to approach this, one of the simplest is to read, then process/convert into the array of digits with `sscanf`. You can adjust the limits and types as needed (16 digit max below). If your needs are different, drop a comment. Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>  

#define MAXN 16

int main(void)
{
    unsigned char a[MAXN] = {0};
    unsigned i = 0, n = 0;
    char str[MAXN] = {0};
    char *p = str;

    printf("\nEnter a number : ");
    scanf (" %[^\n]%*c", str); /* read as char, to digits below */
    while (*p && sscanf (p, " %1hhu", &a[i++]) == 1 && i < MAXN) {
        p++;
    }

    /* output array below */
    n = i;

    puts ("");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf ("  a[%d] : %d\n", i, a[i]);
    puts ("");

    return 0;
}
```

**Input/Output**

```
$ ./bin/scanf_array

Enter a number : 987654321

  a[0] : 9
  a[1] : 8
  a[2] : 7
  a[3] : 6
  a[4] : 5
  a[5] : 4
  a[6] : 3
  a[7] : 2
  a[8] : 1
```

**Note:** if you expect to handle a negative input, you will need to preserve the sign before you convert the number to digits and apply it in some fashion later.